# Is it safe to `.Select` an `out` parameter that was set in a preceding `.Where` clause (with `TryParse`)?

Tags: c#

I have some code that I'm shortening from a loop to a Linq statement, but it feels dangerous to do so.

Is it safe to `.Select` an `out` parameter value that was set in the preceding `.Where` clause (with `TryParse`) within the same statement? The main reason I ask is that I got a compile error in the `Select` statement that *"local variable `val` may not be initialized before accessing"*, even though it should be guaranteed in the `Where` clause, so I had to assign `val` a "dummy" value to get this to compile.

```
var items = new List<string>();

// out parameters don't have to be assigned first, but the compiler forced me to.
int val = 0;

var result = items
    .Where(item => int.TryParse(item, out val))
    .Select(i => val)
    .ToList();
```

In my limited testing it seems to produce the correct results, even if I remove the `.ToList` and change the value of `val`.

Are there any "gotchas" here?

Comment: That seems like a Bad Idea(tm). I would rather do something like `items.Select(i => new { gotIt: dict.TryGetValue(i, out string val), gotWhat: val }).Where(i => i.gotIt).Select(i => i.gotWhat).ToList()`; just to be sure

Comment: `even though it should be guaranteed in the Where clause` The compiler is not smart enough to realise that the code in `Where` will definitely happen - hence the warning.

Comment: @mjwills That's a good point. This example is actually from another question here, but I'm mostly asking about the pattern of passing an `out` parameter in the `Where` and then using it in the `Select`.

Comment: It is weird, since it is taking this variable outside of the LINQ expression and making it quite central to the correct operation of the LINQ. Hence why I would do it the tuple way (my suggestion is basically the same as Heretic's). In other words, have the LINQ self contained.

Comment: `This example is actually from another question here, but I'm mostly asking about the pattern of passing an out parameter in the Where and then using it in the Select.` Will it work? Generally yes (as long as it is all LINQ to Objects and you are reading it _immediately_ after so sorting etc can't mess you up - it clearly won't work in EF for example). Is it a good idea? I'd avoid it if an alternative is available.

Comment: `AsParallel` is an example of something that could likely cause havoc with your current approach @RufusL.

Comment: I wouldn't do this. The fact you have to ask the question here demonstrates it's not immediately clear how it would behave. Honestly, I see nothing wrong with using a `foreach` instead. LINQ isn't always better.

Comment: @JohnH - It's quite possible to make malformed `foreach` statements. What do you see as the benefit of using `foreach` over LINQ?

Comment: @Enigmativity I see your point, but it's possible to write all sorts of malformed statements. The difference with the foreach is it is much simpler because there is no having to guess about the implementation of LINQ itself, and the suggestion of writing extension methods and such to handle something like this, in my view, is over-engineering. KISS.

Comment: The code you posted is awful, for the very reason that it's obfuscated. There are many different alternatives that would work instead and which would be _clearly_ correct, rather than making the reader of the code scratch their head (my preferred would be to use an intermediate anonymous-typed object to capture both parts of the `TryParse()` result...i.e. `.Select(...).Where(...).Select(...)` or the query expression equivalent. First projection sets up the data, while the `Where()` and second projection make use of that.

Comment: @JohnH - I'm going to continue to play Devil's Advocate, if that's OK. Can you tell me when you have to "guess about the implementation of LINQ itself"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels unsafe, but I struggled to make a situation where it failed using a single thread.

If we go multi-threaded then all bets are off anyway.

The fact that the `Select` immediately follows the `Where` and there is no intermediate manipulation of the `val` variable makes this safe ***in this particular example***.

However, this kind of thing can easily go wrong, and, as a good coder, we know to avoid external state on LINQ expressions.

Fortunately there are a number of ways around this. My favourite is this:

```
var result =
    items
        .SelectMany(item =>
            int.TryParse(item, out int val)
            ? new[] { val }
            : Enumerable.Empty<int>())
        .ToList();
```

Or even:

```
var result =
    items
        .Select(item =>
            int.TryParse(item, out int val)
            ? (int?)val
            : (int?)null)
        .Where(val => val.HasValue)
        .Select(val => val.Value)
        .ToList();
```

---

If you want to use the original code, but make sure it is safe then here's a simple extension method to do so:

```
public static IEnumerable<R> Capture<T, R>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<R>> transform)
{
    foreach (var r in transform(source))
    {
        yield return r;
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```
var result =
    items
        .Capture(xs =>
        {
            int val = 0;
            return
                xs
                    .Where(item => int.TryParse(item, out val))
                    .Select(i => val);
        });
```

Comment: `If we go multi-threaded then all bets are off anyway.` To be fair, that is only because of the use of the shared state (i.e. a good argument for not using the shared state). Without the variable outside of the LINQ statement parallel is generally very safe...

Comment: @mjwills - Yes, well, that's true. I was just trying to say that I considered the multi-threaded case, but wasn't going to go into it any further.

Answer (score 1):

That probably works, but not safe. Here’s a safer alternative.

```
/// <summary>A generic delegate for <see cref="selectWhere{TSource, TResult}(IEnumerable{TSource}, pfnSelectWhere{TSource, TResult})" /></summary>
public delegate bool pfnSelectWhere<TSource, TResult>( TSource source, out TResult result );

/// <summary>Combined Where + Select extension method for lazily-evaluated sequences</summary>
public static IEnumerable<TResult> selectWhere<TSource, TResult>( this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        pfnSelectWhere<TSource, TResult> selector )
{
    foreach( var i in source )
        if( selector( i, out var r ) )
            yield return r;
}

// Usage example
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var items = new List<string>();
    List<int> result = items
        .selectWhere( ( string s, out int v ) => int.TryParse( s, out v ) )
        .ToList();
}
```